# Determine when an APPX installed via PowerShell is ready

Tags: powershell, winrt-xaml

I've got a minor problem.

For an internal Windows 8 application I'm using a loader (WPF), which updates the application if needed.

The loader installs the APPX using the `Add-AppxPackage` powershell command, fired via `Process.Start`. The application waits for the command to finish (`process.WaitForExitAsync()`).

Here's the tricky part. At this point, since the install process was finished and didn't return any errors (those are logged and stop the application) I **should** be able to run the installed application, right?

Wrong.

I start the application using the `shell:appsfolder\\<MyApplicationFullName>!App` command (again, via `Process.Start`), but if I do this exactly as soon as the install command finishes, I'll get an error `The system cannot find the path specified`.

If I wait a few seconds the above command will work fine.

I've tried using the command `Get-AppxPackage` to get the status of my application. Again, despite being installed and listed, I cannot run it if I don't wait a few moments.

I'd like to make the install / update process as fast as possible and hardcoding a delay doesn't seem appropriate.

What could I do to determine if / when my application can be run?